# Preparing GD dynamic image for upload

Tags: php, image, dynamic, upload, gd

How can I prepare a dynamic image created by GD for upload?

I created a php script to create dynamic images based on the userid (EX: www.mywebsite.com/image/124.png <== that should show the user 124 info)

Now I need to upload it to Facebook with this script :

```
$photo_details = array(
    'message'=> $message
);
$file = "$_GET[id].png";
$photo_details['image'] = '@/home/username/public_html/image/' . $file;
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
```

When I use the upload script that way I get this error:

*Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data*

But If I uploaded 124.png to /image/ directory and and tried the same code again with using the ID 124 it works just fine. After a long research I came to conclusion the problem relay in the dynamic part since it works just fine with static images. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the script tries to read the *file* directly from the filesystem instead of running the image generating script. You can solve this by setting `$photo_details['image'] = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/image/'.$file;` if Facebook class allows this kind of file opening.